# What does it mean to have -1 confirmations?

Tags: transactions, wallet, client, confirmations, electrum

I have -1 confirmations for an inbound transaction on my Electrum wallet. What does is it mean to have -1 confirmations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug, just restart the client and/or switch to another server in the Network window (green dot in the bottom right).

If this doesn't fix the 'Unverified -1 confirmation error' try deleting the block_headers folder on your Electrum directory -> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=330626.msg5292794#msg5292794

Comment: If you could give a link to the bug report, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Added another possible fix and a link to one of the reports.